# Start scene from certain point in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new in game development, I am using Unity in combination with C# with Models which are made in Blender.

I was wondering, if there is a way to "play" a scene from a certain point. For example, if I have a game (single scene for simplicity now) and like to test a certain part of the Game (e.g. I would like to test the 3rd of 5th quests within this scene, assuming that you can access the 2nd quest only if you successfully completed the 1st one, and so on).

But I really don't wanna to play through my scene for a while, just to reach the point which I originally wanted to test.

How can i achieve this? And if it is not possible in some simple way, is there some kind of workaround for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should create some scripts for debugging, which allow you to override the current active quest (and artificially check off completion of requisite quests). It's not clear what your code structure/dependencies look like, so that's as specific as I can be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So there is no "unity-way" to achieve this?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all solution for what you're looking for - since every game is structured differently, each one will need its own solution for artificially advancing progression. The only Unity-specific thing I might suggest is making the variables of your debug script public and attaching them to an empty object in the scene - this will save you time when you need to quickly change values to try out different quests.

Comment: Why can't you open the scene you want to test in the unity editor and play that scene?

Comment: @Lews Therin yes I can do that, but that is not my point. I want to avoid playing through the whole scene (I am referring to a single scene) if I want to test something in my game, which appears at the "end" of this scene (if you treat a single scene like a single level).

Comment: @Sebastian Okay, that wasn't clear from your question. To accomplish what you want, I'd go with Serlite's suggestion of making some sort of debug script that sets up the scene in the state you want to test (specific quests completed, specific items in a character's inventory, specific character stats, etc). You can bind this script to run only if you set a debug flag as true (you can publicly expose this flag so you can easily change it from Unity's inspector).

Comment: No, there is no "Unity Way" of doing this. Unity doesn't know what a Quest is: that's your code. Every single line of code you write you need to write your own shortcuts for so you can test it. There's no universal magic wand that will fast-forward things. You might be able to cheese it through a debugger, by manually altering values in memory, but you can achieve the same result by writing cheat-codes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want to jump from scene to scene, within your project, you can always use the sceneManager.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, i have thought of something like skipping the gameplay (within the same scene (!)), so I don't have to play through the whole scene if I e.g. want to test something at the end of this scene (if scene is e.g. a single level in the game).

Comment: It all depends on what your game format is, and what are the variables or properties of your game that change. If we are for example talking about score, then I would suggest as everyone else does - to make the variables that are affected by progression public, and that would allow you to change the values straight from the editor. If you want to test if a player has walked through something for example, I would setup an empty object with a collider set as isTrigger. You can toggle the isTrigger directly from the editor as well. Hope that helps and gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, create a variable that holds the value for starting quest. e.g. 3.

Then for testing purpose, in the Start() method, you can check the value of that variable and write some code to change the elements in the scene to represent the corresponding quest(3 in this case) like the position of the character, or next objective or anything that is specific to the quest.

You can make this variable public so that you can change its value from unity instead of opening the script every time.

I am not sure if it is feasible for your game, but if you have a lot of things that change for each quest, it is best to have a different scene for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code on how i did it.. hope this will help you..
Create a C# script called GoScene1

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GoScene1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Scene1Change() {
        Application.LoadLevel("GoScene1");
    }
}
```

Then Create a C# Script Called GoScene2

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GoScene2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Scene2Change() {
        Application.LoadLevel("GoScene2");
    }
}
```

Heres the Screen shot...[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I really thing you guys don't really understand what I want to do. I want to "play" a single scene from a certain point (not switching between scenes, loading another scene, etc.)